# How to modify and store settings in laravel for use in kernel

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a job that's scheduled to run daily. I would like to allow users to modify the schedule to say on Monday the task shouldn't run.

Where would be the best place to store this information so it can be retrieved when the `kernel.php` file is ran?

I don't want to store in database as am concerned of adding unnecessary overhead to the kernel and I don't believe I should be modifying the env file programmatically either?

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the database? This is the safest user experience. After all, this schedule will be set by them. And the additional load from accessing the database can be neglected, because you will still implement the storage of this information.
**the easiest way is the surest**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, Laravel tasks are executed by setting up a cron task running every minutes and calling `php artisan schedule:run`.

This command then looks inside the `App\Console\Kernel.php` file and executes every commands (or jobs or closures) that need to run.

If you want each user to determine on which days something should be done, you must save this configuration inside your database (for instance, in your `users` table, but it could be really anywhere). Trust me, storing these settings in the database in a per user basis is the way to go.

Think about it like a user setting.

Then, you should set up a command to run every days (in your `Kernel.php` file).

This command will run every days, but inside it, you'll only get the users that needs something to be done on the particular day it is executed.

It could looks like something like this:

```php
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::query()->whereHas('day_of_weeks', function($q){
        $q->where('number', today()->dayOfWeek);
    })->get();

    // $users will be populated with users that have a related day_of_weeks relationship that include the today()->dayOfWeek number

    // you can now loops through those users and do whatever you want
}
```

Keep in mind the code above will not work "as it is", you'll need to implement those relationships... this is just an example, among many other ways to achieve this.

The important part to understand is that a user setting will almost always be stored in the database. After that, you:

- execute your cron task every days to ensure it'll be executed for every possible user settings.
- filter your users and loop only on those who need it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with such a detailed answer.  I didn't properly communicate this would be accessible to all users and they would all share the same setting instance. However, the essence is the same. Thank you